# Minecraft survival mode monsters

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft PC I was on survival. I went on peaceful then switched to normal but no monsters are spawning. Why?

Comment: Is it dark? How long have you waited?

Comment: Has it been a while since they didn't spawn back or was it straight after you changed it you expected to see them?

Comment: Have you tried relogging?

Answer (score 0):

Monsters only spawn in areas of darkness (eg. a cave or at night-time) and will not spawn within a certain number of blocks of you. Try walking around for a bit and see if they start appearing then. remember they won't spawn instantly, you have to wait for a bit.

If everything above is correct, and they still won't spawn, try closing and reopening the game, or relogging it. if none of these things work it could be glitch, or a corrupted world, in which case you'll either have o try to fix it, or start a new world.